# How to constrain a view to a UITextView's first baseline?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uitextview, baseline

I'm desperately trying to constrain the first baselines of a `UILabel` and a `UITextView` in Interface Builder. From my understanding this should be quite easy by simply adding the following constraint (Pseudo-Code):

```
label.firstBaseline = textView.firstBaseline
```

However, depending on the other constraints and some view settings I get really awkward results as shown in the following screenshots.

#### 1st Case: Disable scrolling & Align the top edges

This is only for showing the general view setup. I have disabled scrolling for the `textView` to avoid ambiguity. (Otherwise the `textView` cannot calculate its own height from its containing text.)

[image: 1st case: Align top edges of both views]

#### 2nd Case: Disable scrolling & align the first baselines

Same setup as in the 1st case with the only difference that I have removed the constraint that aligns the top edges of the views and added a constraint that aligns the first baselines of the views instead.

For some reason, the label "takes off" well beyond the bounds of its superview and ends up at a y position of 7764. No idea why.

[image: 2nd case: Align first baselines]

#### 3rd Case: Constrain height & align the first baselines

Now I have scrolling enabled for the `textView` and constrained its height instead.

Obviously the `label`'s first baseline gets aligned with the `textView`s top edge even though the constrained says to align both their first baselines. I read in the Apple docs that the `firstBaseline` parameter returns a view's top edge if that view doesn't have a baseline. So it seems that the `textView` doesn't have a first baseline in this scenario.

[image: 3rd case: Align first baselines and add height constraint]

Does a `UITextView` in general have no `firstBaseline`?
And if so: Why? After all, it's a view that draws text and thus this property should be set.

Any thoughts on this are appreciated.

Comment: have you found a solution for this issue?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: I ended with adding a hidden dummy label with the same font as the text view (TV), aligning it to the element that I wanted the TV to be aligned to, and the TV is aligned to the top of the label (with offset of textView.contentInset.top + textView.textContainerInset.top)..